# Product listing by departament - total values

Tags: python

I'm new to python so i apologize in advance if this is a stupid question and if possible please help me. I have to make a program that reads the number of sectors, the number of products and the price list of products by sector.
The program must print a matrix with the list of product prices and the total sum of prices by sector.
I wrote this code, but it didn't work.

```
from numpy import*             
qs = int(input())      
qp = int(input())
m = array(eval(input()))
n = array(eval(input()))
o = array(eval(input()))
t1 = sum(m)
t2 = sum(n)
t3 = sum(o)
print("The total of sector 1 is:",(round(t1)),"dollars")
print("The total of sector 2 is:",(round(t2)),"dollars")
print("The total of sector 3 is:",(round(t3)),"dollars")
print(matrix(m,n,o))
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: so i don't feel like i have a good sense of what you are trying to do here, but you may want to look into the `pandas` library. It is a popular library (built on a lot of numpy stuff) that uses dataframes (think a table or sheet in excel) and can manipulate, aggregate, display, and lots more. it is just `pip install pandas`, and the docs are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Comment: the matrix is ​​not printing

Comment: The matrix it not printing because you're getting an error.  I'm not sure how you missed the error.  That's not how you call the `np.matrix` function.  However, you shouldn't be using that, anyway.  Just build an array using your three arrays as rows.  I will show you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix it not printing because you're getting an error.  That's not how you call the `np.matrix` function.  However, you shouldn't be using that, anyway.  Just build an array using your three arrays as rows, after adding the sum to the row:

```
import numpy as np
qs = int(input())      
qp = int(input())
m = eval(input())
n = eval(input())
o = eval(input())
m = np.array( m+[sum(m)] )
n = np.array( n+[sum(n)] )
o = np.array( o+[sum(o)] )
print("The total of sector 1 is:",(round(m[-1])),"dollars")
print("The total of sector 2 is:",(round(n[-1])),"dollars")
print("The total of sector 3 is:",(round(o[-1])),"dollars")
mx = np.array((m,n,o))
print(mx)
```

Input:

```
3
3
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[10,11,12]
```

Output:

```
The total of sector 1 is: 15 dollars
The total of sector 2 is: 24 dollars
The total of sector 3 is: 33 dollars
[[ 4  5  6 15]
 [ 7  8  9 24]
 [10 11 12 33]]
```